# Upload more than 15 GB Video File from android to node.js server

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, ftp, upload

Is there any one who can help me **upload more than 15 GB Video File** from android to node.js server using **socket.io or FTP or any**, because I am trying to upload via Retrofit but it can not upload above than 1.5 GB.

Thank You!

Comment: Could the video file be compressed? If not I guess you could use something like multer (a middleware for node.js) to kick it off quickly.

Comment: you should send the video file in chunks.

Comment: you can use multer in node.js .

Comment: I have tried with multer but what happen is file is uploaded to server but at android end in the middle of it it will break and gets exception...

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh, how can we send video file in chunks from android?

Comment: have you done it?